# What is the mistake on this javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a function if something is done successfully the Php(include js) return a alert.
But i am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

The whole code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
$name=$POST_['igname'];
$to="body66605@gmail.com";
$subject="Giveaway Participate";
$message="$name has just Participate on the Giveaway";
$headers="From: 'bishow-giveway.x'";

$error="Failed to participate\n Please try again❌";
$success="Successfully participated\n Good Luck✔";

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
     echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$success');</script>";
}
else{
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$error');</script>";
}
}
?>
```

The code where i am getting the error:

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
     echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$success');</script>"; //here is the error
}
```

Comment: On the third line it should be `$_POST`, not `$POST_`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don´t use \n it is ok

```
$error="Failed to participate Please try again❌";
$success="Successfully participated Good Luck✔";
```

Comment: True, but that doesn't _solve_ the issue. What if the newline is needed?

Comment: use \\n instead

Answer (score 0):

You have an interpolation error, because php is decoding your newline character to a *real* newline, which is invalid javascript inside `""` or `''` (but not inside ``` `` ```). So to fix this, either change the javascript quote types to ``` `` ```, or encode you newline *twice*, so that php doesn't decode it before sending it to javascript. (PHP has helpers for this sort of thing, but you can just use `\\n` in this case).

There is a caveat to using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)  (``` `` ``` strings): it is a rather new javascript feature and isn't supported in older browsers. But if you don't need to support older browsers (no versions of IE support it), it's a neat feature.